# ColorFunction in SphericalPlot3D fails with ImageValue

Tags: plotting, color, image, options

I would like to texture and deform a sphere with with images using various mapping functions between x,y and phi,theta. I figure I should start with $f(phi,theta)=(x,y)$ as a test case. However, I have run into a problem.

When I run:

```
lena = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
SphericalPlot3D[1, {ϕ, 1, π}, {θ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, ϕ, θ, r}, RGBColor[ImageValue[lena, {ϕ, θ}]]]
]
```

I receive a number of error messages most notably:

> ```
> ImageValue::imgrng: The specified argument
> {(1. -Graphics`SphericalPlot3DDump`slotfourmin)/(Graphics`SphericalPlot3DDump`slotfourmax-Graphics`SphericalPlot3DDump`slotfourmin),
> (4.48799*10^-7-Graphics`SphericalPlot3DDump`slotfivemin)/(Graphics`SphericalPlot3DDump`slotfivemax-Graphics`SphericalPlot3DDump`slotfivemin)}
> should be an image, a graphics object, or a list of coordinates.
> ```

It seems like `SphericalPlot3D` is trying to get a range on the color values my color function generates and for some reason it does this with the symbols like `` Graphics`SphericalPlot3DDump`slotfivemin `` instead of numerical values.

I can try to get around this like so:

```
cf[x_, y_, z_, ϕ_NumericQ, θ_NumericQ, r_] :=RGBColor[ImageValue[lena, {ϕ *10, θ *10}]]

SphericalPlot3D[1, {ϕ, 0, π}, {θ, 0, 2 Pi}, ColorFunction -> cf]
```

But that just produces an ordinary sphere with some weird triangular artifacts.

This maybe an XY problem, and I would be interested in other solutions to this color mapping and deforming problem, maybe using `PlotStyle->Texture["imag"]`

Comment: This scheme works perfectly with Plot3D:
`Plot3D[Max[ImageValue[lena, {x, y}]], {x, 0, 500}, {y, 0, 500}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, RGBColor[ImageValue[lena, {x*500, y*500}]]], 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 120, Mesh -> None]`

Comment: you can try `SphericalPlot3D[1, {\[Phi], 1, \[Pi]}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> Texture[lena]]`

Answer (score 1):

Won't comment on reasons or alternative solutions now but this seems to do the trick:

```
lena = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];

img[ϕ_?NumericQ, θ_?NumericQ] :=  RGBColor[ImageValue[lena, 512 {ϕ, θ}]]

SphericalPlot3D[1, {ϕ, 1, π}, {θ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 ColorFunction ->  Function[{x, y, z, ϕ, θ, r}, img[ϕ, θ]], 
 PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image]